# How can alter text in a loop in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text inside a DIV tag.  Is it possible to change the text content with five different text contents in cycle that never ends?  Sounds simple, but I'm trying to find the easiest approach with jquery or related.

Many thanks,
Erik

Comment: Could you please provide some sample input/output data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really simple approach: use `setInterval()`.

```
var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    i = 0,
    $div = $('#myDiv');

setInterval(function ()
{
    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]);
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TJv3K/

---

***Edit*** If you want to get fancier with the effects: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TJv3K/1/

---

***Edit 2*** re OP comments (below)

- **[Fix #1](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/MFkWK/)**: use distinct variable names for each rotator, because variable scoping is unaffected by `<script>` tags.
- **[Fix #2](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/JjBfd/)**: don't change variable names, but use closures so that the global scope isn't polluted.

Other fixes needed (shown in both fiddles):

- Actually load jQuery from somewhere, otherwise none of this code will work.

  ```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ```
- Remove the trailing comma at the end of the first `text` array literal
- Change the semicolons following the two `text` array declarations to commas, otherwise the following variables (`i` and `$div`) will be declared as global, which is a **bad thing.**

Comment: Thank you.  It works, but what only works when I have more than two tags I want to change text.  Is there a way to have multiple tags changing?

Comment: Sure, the problem is that the code isn't scoped to the `<script>` tags - `text`, `i`, and `$div` are all global. You either need to (1) use different variable names for each rotator's variables, or (2) enclose what you now have in separate script tags in separate closures. I'll throw together jsfiddles showing each. Oh, also, you have a trailing comma in the first `text` array, which will cause some browsers to choke.

Comment: ...also, ***big problem,*** the page never loads jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say your intentions, but you can use `setInterval` to trigger a timer to append/change info in the `div`.

```
<div id="change">initial content</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
      setInterval(update, 1000);
    });

    function update() {
      $("#change").append(".");
    }
</script>
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/ACjGS/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbkjE/11/. It's a bit bigger than this because I added some elements to display the clockwork that's happening.

Here's the code:

```
var strings = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar', 'BarFoo', 'FooBarFoo'];
var index = 0;

function cycle()
{
    $('#cycle').text(strings[index % strings.length]);
    index++;

    setTimeout(cycle, 500);
}

cycle();
```

You just cycle through the values of the array, and to do that, you modulo the length of the array (Google "modulo operator").

And a (kinda) one-liner:

```
var index = 0;
var strings = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar', 'BarFoo', 'FooBarFoo'];

$(function() { setInterval(function() {$('#cycle').text(strings[index++ % strings.length]);}, 1000); });
```